# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' Tried escaping but not works

Tags: javascript

I am having issues with the following javascript,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var $OriginalImage = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SUwv0x4nozI/UjBwsjK1AGI/AAAAAAAAZAI/HgfzndxJ_Nk/s1600/Android+Wallpaper.jpg';
var $thumbnail = $OriginalImage.replace('s1600','s320');

document.write = '<img alt='Android Monochrome Wallpaper' class='img-responsive img-hover' src=' +$thumbnail+ '/>';
</script>
```

**in the console it got error(s).**

[image: screenshot]

I have tried the `document.write();` markup to be escaped but it didn;t work... How to fix this issue?

Comment: You have a quote-problem. Try `document.write = '<img alt="Android Monochrome Wallpaper" class="img-responsive img-hover" src="' +$thumbnail+ '"/>';`

Comment: Also `document.write` is a function. You have to call it, not assign to it.

Comment: Also, create an img element instead of using `document.write` and insert it with `appendChild`

Comment: `var img = document.createElement('img');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the properly escaped result:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var OriginalImage = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SUwv0x4nozI/UjBwsjK1AGI/AAAAAAAAZAI/HgfzndxJ_Nk/s1600/Android+Wallpaper.jpg';
    var thumbnail = OriginalImage.replace('s1600','s320');
    document.write('<img alt="Android Monochrome Wallpaper" class="img-responsive img-hover" src="' +thumbnail+ '"/>');
</script>
```

But as @limelights says in comments, instead of document.write, go for appendChild

```js
  var OriginalImage = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SUwv0x4nozI/UjBwsjK1AGI/AAAAAAAAZAI/HgfzndxJ_Nk/s1600/Android+Wallpaper.jpg';
  var thumbnail = OriginalImage.replace('s1600', 's320');

  var DOM_img = document.createElement("img");
  DOM_img.alt = "Android Monochrome Wallpaper";
  DOM_img.class = "img-responsive img-hover"
  DOM_img.src = thumbnail;
  document.body.appendChild(DOM_img);
```

or using setAttribute:

```js
var OriginalImage = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SUwv0x4nozI/UjBwsjK1AGI/AAAAAAAAZAI/HgfzndxJ_Nk/s1600/Android+Wallpaper.jpg';

var thumbnail = OriginalImage.replace('s1600', 's320');
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", thumbnail);
elem.setAttribute("class", "img-responsive img-hover");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Android Monochrome Wallpaper");
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Append to anchor tag:

```js
var OriginalImage = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SUwv0x4nozI/UjBwsjK1AGI/AAAAAAAAZAI/HgfzndxJ_Nk/s1600/Android+Wallpaper.jpg';

    var thumbnail = OriginalImage.replace('s1600', 's320');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.setAttribute("src", thumbnail);
    elem.setAttribute("class", "img-responsive img-hover");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", "Android Monochrome Wallpaper");
    document.getElementById('addImage').appendChild(elem);
```

```html
<a href="example.html" id="addImage"></a>
```

or without ID:

```js
var OriginalImage = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SUwv0x4nozI/UjBwsjK1AGI/AAAAAAAAZAI/HgfzndxJ_Nk/s1600/Android+Wallpaper.jpg';

    var thumbnail = OriginalImage.replace('s1600', 's320');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.setAttribute("src", thumbnail);
    elem.setAttribute("class", "img-responsive img-hover");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", "Android Monochrome Wallpaper");
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].appendChild(elem);
```

```html
<a href="example.html"></a>
```

Comment: yes, but how to do that? Just add this `var img = document.createElement('img');` ? Where will be other attributes goes? Like Class, Alt

Comment: thanks for the answer. Instead of appending on body `  document.body.appendChild(DOM_img); ` i want to append it with an `<a>` i have placed the script within the `a` tag but the image is not appending within a tag.

Comment: I have tried both ways, the `DOM_img ` way works in Firefox and in chrome, but it does not recognizes any attributes supplied. and in Internet Explore, it doesnt recognizes anything. pics are not loaded at all. So i tried the next method the `elem` way, it works on Chrome and Firefox, and same happens in Explorer pics are not loaded. What to do?

Comment: What version of IE are you using?